# Cannot use Onsen UI in visual studio Multi-Device Hybrid App (Cordova) Project

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, onsen-ui, visual-studio-cordova

I have been trying for a long time but I cannot get OnsenUI to work on visual studio 2013 Multi-Device Hybrid App (Cordova) Project. Below is the link to my project.https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DBAFE70AF18A9BDB%211817.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Onsen UI extension for Visual Studio 2015 [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8968a18d-cc94-4ebf-8183-ed0e1f6247f3).

If you open that VSIX file as a Zip file you will find some templates prepared for Windows Phone and Visual Studio 2015 with Onsen UI, AngularJS and Cordova. Just adapt the folder structure to VS2013 (i.e. without 'www' folder) and they will work. More info in [Onsen UI blog](http://onsen.io/blog/onsen-ui-templates-windows-phone-visual-studio/).

Hope it helps!